# What to do about 5 tags: share, sharing, share-menu, screen-share, screen-sharing?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I guess the subject already shows a lot of redundancy concerning "sharing". Keeping in mind different meanings:

- sharing of files, texts, pictures, etc. via the share menu
- sharing a geo-location using services like e.g. Latitude
- sharing a connection (for which we already have the [tether](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tether) and [reverse-tether](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reverse-tether) tags
- sharing a screen
- other means of sharing a device (which will probably have other tags like multi-user when needed, as soon as 4.2 comes out with that feature)

I'd suggest the following:

- merging [share](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/share) (x29) and [sharing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharing) (x13), optionally with [share-menu](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/share-menu) (x1), making one the "master" and the other(s) synonym(s)
- merging [screen-share](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-share) (x1) and [screen-sharing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-sharing) (x1), making one the master and the other a synonym to it

Comment: `share` is a complete mess.  I think we should have `share-menu` solely for questions specifically about the menu, plus `screen-sharing`, and eliminate the rest.  I don't care that you're uploading your photos because you want to "share" them, that's useless as a tag.

Comment: I agree with you, @MatthewRead. And I surely didn't mean to count "uploading things to share" within this range. I meant to distinguish between share-menu, screen-sharing, geolocation-sharing, and possibly overlooked other sharing methods we can care about when they come up. In other terms: I share your concern ;) But it still leaves open how to tag a question about sharing a geo-location (Latitude or otherwise), as this has nothing to do with the share-menu or screen-sharing. Do we need a location-sharing tag then?

Comment: I'd stick with just `geolocation` or whatever the relevant tags are, I'm not sure that `location-sharing` is a coherent problem class.

Comment: OK, let's postpone that until it becomes such :) So I'm with you and your first comment here.

Comment: Yeah, I think "shar(e|ing)" are not  useful tags. Fortunately there's not too many of them.

Comment: Heh. Now that I've retagged a bunch of stuff with "share-menu" and otherwise cleaned up "share" and "sharing" I found a lot of dupes. Gotta go back and report 'em.

Comment: @AlEverett Yeah, that's how I often find (and v-c) dupes. Guess why so many merge requests came from me recently :) So thanks for merging. Q: Did you mark the "emptied tags" to become synonyms? I see e.g. sharing is empty now. If so, how long does it take to get active, or does it need to be manually approved? Looks like the similar question which arose yesterday on the (emptied-on-merge) configuration tag (maybe you could check for that one whether it needs approval, so we know for the next time and don't get confused next time ;).

Comment: @MatthewRead See previous comment: Remember our problem with the "configuration" tag yesterday? Now you've probably got the chance to check with the "sharing" tag, if it got queued somewhere and needs approval. Unfortunately, I cannot (yet) do that myself, not enough rep ;)

Comment: Not a Mod. I can only suggest or vote on synonyms, and only if I meet the criteria in the tag.

Comment: @AlEverett Thanks anyway! As it worked out in the other case (configuration ./. settings), I'm confident it will do here as well (though e.g. "sharing" still seems empty and not yet synonymized).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since [screen-share](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-share) and [screen-sharing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/screen-sharing) are so similar I didn't synonymize, just kept the latter.  If you start typing the former, the latter should pop up before you finish.

[share](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/share) and [sharing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sharing) should now be empty and should be automatically deleted in 24 hours or so.

One related case I found was [file-sharing](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-sharing).  I'm not sure if this is necessarily a good tag but it's better than the ones we removed, so I left it.  Other questions may need to be retagged to use it if we want to keep it.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep my eyes open for those "others". I think `file-sharing` should be kept. Let me see to provide it a summary: This should be used e.g. for torrent stuff as well as on-device "file servers" (ftpd and the like) IMHO.

Comment: @Izzy I'd keep those separate since the methods involved are pretty distinct.  Probably `torrenting` would be sufficient for the first since I don't think ED2K or other P2P networks are popular with Android :P.  Possibly `file-shares` would be clearer than `file-sharing` for FTP/SMB/etc, what do you think?

Comment: I guess we could split this up later when needed. I just created the tag info -- feel free to update, as I completely forgot about Samba :)